# Solidity 0.6.0 and address(f) to f.address

Tags: solidity, contract-upgrading

I was struck by this Solidity 0.6.0 breaking change:

> Change address(f) to f.address for f being of external function type.

Not a big deal, but I'm clearly very ignorant here. 2 stupid questions. Q1: I use

```
contractAddress.f()
```

a lot, where 'contractAddress' is the contract's Ethereum address, and f is some external function in that contract. Does this imply I should change my code to write

```
f.contractAddress()
```

instead? Q2: Does this mean I should change

```
address(this)
```

to

```
this.address
```

?

Comment: I don't know Solidity 0.6.0, but I find it hard to believe that you should do `f.contractAddress()`, where `f` is the function name and `contractAddress` is the contract instance. It would be pretty much the opposite of the convention in any other language of sort.

Answer (score 3):

This change is about external function types. As you can read in the [Breaking Changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes):

> Conversions from external function types to `address` are now
>   disallowed. Instead external function types have a member called
>   `address`, similar to the existing `selector` member.

First of all, as the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#function-types) says:

> External functions consist of an address and a function signature and
>   they can be passed via and returned from external function calls.

---

**Solidity v0.5.15**

In Solidity docs (`v0.5.15`) about [Function Types](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.15/types.html#function-types) (Conversions) you can read the following:

> A value of external function type can be explicitly converted to
>   `address` resulting in the address of the contract of the function.

Code (taken from the `Oracle` example):

```
pragma solidity 0.5.15;

contract Test {

    struct Request {
        function(uint) external callback;
    }

    Request[] private requests;

    function getAddress (uint requestID) public view returns (address) {
        return address(requests[requestID].callback);
    }
}
```

---

**Solidity v0.6.0**

The conversion is now disallowed. If you try the code above you will see something like that:

[image]

We must update the code like that:

> Change `address(f)` to `f.address` for `f` being of external function type.

If you go to Solidity docs (`v0.6.0`) and read about [Function Types](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/types.html#function-types) (Members) there is a new member:

> - `.address` returns the address of the contract of the function.

Code (taken from the `Oracle` example):

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract Test {

    struct Request {
        function(uint) external callback;
    }

    Request[] private requests;

    function getAddress (uint requestID) public view returns (address) {
        return requests[requestID].callback.address;
    }
}
```

With the code examples I just want to illustrate the compilation error.

---

**Answering your questions:**

Q1: No. Calling functions works in the same way.

Example:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract Contract1 {

    mapping (address => uint256) votes;

    function voteCandidate(address _address) external {
        votes[_address]++;
    }

    function checkVotesCandidate(address _address) public view returns (uint) {
        return votes[_address];
    }
}

contract Caller1 {

    Contract1 c1;

    constructor(address _address) public {
        c1 = Contract1(_address);
    }

    function voteCandidate() public {
        c1.voteCandidate(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Q2: If you use `this.address` you will get a compilation error because it was deprecated in Solidity v0.5, so you must use `address(this)`.

Comment: That's a great answer. I was looking for this as well. Good job.